# Access recursive SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I have a given MS Access Database with one table:

```
ID, Name, Chief
1, Max, NULL
2, Meier, Max
3, Maier, Meier
4, Mueller, Meier
5, Schmitz, Max
....
```

Now I want to do a select to get a list of all Persons in their     hierarchical structure:

```
Max => Meier => Maier
Max => Meier => Mueller
Max => Schmitz
```

Can this be done with SQL and UNION? How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not in Access SQL.

But, for a fixed count, say, six of levels deep, you can use a query with subqueries with subqueries ... etc. if you have a limited count of levels.